# IOS what's the best type for handing INDIVIDUAL unicode chars? wchar_t ? UTF32Char?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I have a set of legacy data that that include individual Unicode chars formed based on struct:

```
struct LocalGrRec{
    wchar_t     cBegin;
    int         x2;
    wchar_t     cEnd;
    in          x2;
};
```

and a typical record looks like this, i.e., includes both long and short Unicode characters

```
{L'a', 0, L'¥', 3}
```

I can change the struct to make it easier to handle reading these characters into character variables:

```
wchar_t   c = rec.cBegin; 
// or
UTF32Char c = rec.cBegin;
```

Which one (or perhaps another choice that I don't know of) would make it easier to handle it. Please note that I need to process them as individual chars, but eventually I'll need to include them in an NSString.

What solution gives me the maximum flexibility and minimum pain?

And how would I read that character into a NSString?

Thanks

edit:
I need to compose NSString with it, not the other way around. 
With unichar, here's the problem:

```
unichar c = L'•'; 
NSLog(@"%c", c);     // produces: (") wrong character, presumably the first half of '•'
NSLog(@"%C", c);     // produces: (\342\200)
```

Comment: What about `unichar`? See the docs for `NSString characterAtIndex`

Comment: I need to compose NSString with it, not the other way around. With unichar, here's the problem:
    unichar c  = L'•';
    NSLog(@"%c", c);
    NSLog(@"%C", c);

the first one prints a wrong character (presumably the first held of the code) and the second one prints:\342\200

Comment: There is no need for the `L` before the character literals with `unichar`.

Comment: Depends on the character. 'a' need it, but '•' needs it. If I don't include it, Xcode complains: Character too large for enclosing character literal type.

Comment: I discovered that if the Text Encoding in Xcode is changed from the default of UTF-8 to UTF-16, then '•'  does not require a preceding L! But I'm having a hard time changing all the files' encodings to UTF-16. Should I? There's almost no documentation on this, but what governs my choice of encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this method:

```
[NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar*) length:(NSUInteger)];
```

Just pass it an array of unichars and a length, and it will give you a NSString back

```
unichar list[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
NSString *listString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:list length:3];
NSLog(@"listString: %@", listString);
```

Comment: This works for shorter characters. But with true Unicode characters it fails: unichar list[3] = {'A', L'•', 'C'};
    NSString *listString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:list length:3];
    NSLog(@"listString: %@", listString); produces: listString: A• the third character is not part of listString now.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it produced: listString: A•C        . I'm on Xcode6 , iOS8.1

Comment: Thanks Alext! I'm on Xcode 6.1 and running iOS 8.1 as well, and I still get A•  I see that other say that this maybe related to the encoding used. Maybe that's what's the difference between your set up and mine?

Comment: I did some research and played around with some potential solutions and couldn't find anything. Are you actually saying you copied and pasted my code and you get a different result? Then I'd say it's an Xcode setting somewhere changing the result somehow?